# X-times as many.....than.....

Tags: grammaticality

I know it is correct to say:

Today, at the conference we have had **5 times as many people as** yesterday.

But does it sound correct to say???:

Today, at the conference we have had **5 times as many people than we had** yesterday.

Today, at the conference we have had **5 times as many people than what we had** yesterday.

Ta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any of those three are correct and they all sound OK to me. "... than we had yesterday" sounds a little clearer and is less verbose.

But the beginning ("we have had...") is a little odd. I would either say "we have..." (if the conference is ongoing) or "we had..." (if it's over).

Answer (score 1):

I would not say 'five times as many ... than' in any context, but always 'five times as many ... as', as in your first example.

'Today at the conference we have had 5 times as many people as we had yesterday' is correct. Saying or writing 'than what we had' or 'as what we had' are incorrect. The use of 'what' here is ungrammatical.

Comment: +1 I agree. But because  *as many . . .than* should not be used. If using *than* it should be *more . . .than*.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence "Today, at the conference we have had 5 times as many people as yesterday." is grammatically correct but feels a little awkward I'd say "Today the conference had 5 times as many people in attendance as yesterday." same message but a little "easier" for want of a better term when read aloud.